# C# WPF ComboBox ItemsSource Binding Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have an issue with binding ComboBox ItemsSource with a list. I read workplaces from csv file. It can't see the Workplaces list. Please, tell me what is wrong.
xaml:

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" Height="25" Margin="0,18,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Workplaces}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   private BindableCollection<WorkplaceInfo> Workplaces { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Workplaces = new BindableCollection<WorkplaceInfo>(GetWorkplaces());
    }

    private List<WorkplaceInfo> GetWorkplaces()
    {
        List<WorkplaceInfo> workplaces = new List<WorkplaceInfo>();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("Workplaces.csv"))
        {
            using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                //csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap<WorkplaceInfoClassMap>();
                var workplaceInfoList = csvReader.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();
                foreach (var wi in workplaceInfoList)
                {
                    workplaces.Add(new WorkplaceInfo(wi.title, wi.member_of.Split(";")));  
                }
            }
        }
        return workplaces;
    }
}
```

WorkplaceInfo class:

```
class WorkplaceInfo
{
    public String title { get; }
    public String[] memberOfList { get; }

    public WorkplaceInfo(string title, string[] memberOfList)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.memberOfList = memberOfList;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You forgot to set the Window's DataContext. Add `DataContext = this;` to the MainWindow constructor. See [Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: `Workplaces` property has to be public

Answer (score -1):

Here is your code optimized to work:

```
   public ObservableCollection<WorkplaceInfo> Workplaces { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        Workplaces = new ObservableCollection<WorkplaceInfo>(GetWorkplaces());
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private List<WorkplaceInfo> GetWorkplaces()
    {
        List<WorkplaceInfo> workplaces = new List<WorkplaceInfo>();

        try
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("Workplaces.csv"))
            {
                using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
                {
                    //csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap<WorkplaceInfoClassMap>();
                    var workplaceInfoList = csvReader.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();
                    foreach (var wi in workplaceInfoList)
                    {
                        var titl = wi.title;

                        workplaces.Add(new WorkplaceInfo(wi.title, new List<string>() { wi.member_of }.ToArray()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return workplaces;
    }
```

So the changes needed in your code are:

1. Set your Workplaces collection to public ObservableCollection
2. Add DataContext binding
3. Read in the Date and create the collection before the main window is initialized (other way round the UI will not detect the change in you object unless you implement INotifyPropertyChanged event)

p.s. I don't know the structure of your csv file so I made my small demo like (Workplaces.csv) and adopted the parser. You can keep your parser if it matches your csv file structrue.:

```
title;member_of 
London;First 
Amsterdam;Second
```

And my warm recommendation is to use try-catch block always when handling files and when working with anything what is external to your application.

Best regards.

Comment: Setting the DataContext is not "*in any case a MUST*" - only when you not explicitly set a Binding's source object by either Source, RelativeSource or ElementName. Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged is only necessary when the Workplaces property changes after initialization, which it does not seem to do here. Better declare the property readonly. Finally, the property must be declared public, not private.

Comment: That is also not true. Be aware that Bindings are evaluated later. It makes no difference whether you initialize the property before or after InitializeComponent. Also the term "static collection" is incorrect. It is not a static property (but should be a readonly one). The collection itself is still mutable, that's why it should be an ObservableCollection.

Comment: @Clemens this time you are wrong. If there is no implementation of INotifiyPropertyChanged and the Window is loaded first and data created after that DataBinding will not work and ItemsList will be empty. So in this particular case one needs first to create the object and import the data before calling InitializeComponent.

Comment: You could simply try it - instead of making wrong claims.

Comment: Just tried it :-) Why don't you try it.

Comment: Then you did something wrong. The calling order of InitializeComponent, DataContext assignment, and collection property assignment in the MainWindow constructor is irrelevant. As said before, Bindings are evaluated later.

Comment: Really? What? :-) You can copy-paste my code above. Then change the order of InitializeComponent() and ObjectCreation a tell me if it works.

Comment: It works. The calling order of InitializeComponent, DataContext assignment, and collection property assignment in the MainWindow constructor is irrelevant. As said before, Bindings are evaluated later.

Comment: Wait a second. You took my code, changed the order of theese two lines:             InitializeComponent();
            Workplaces = new ObservableCollection<WorkplaceInfo>(GetWorkplaces());  and it worked?

Comment: Sure. Also said before, the Workplaces property should be readonly: `public ObservableCollection<WorkplaceInfo> Workplaces { get; }`. Otherwise you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged for that property.

Comment: This only proves that you didn't try it. If you tried you would know that it doesn't work.